# Need help to replace complex string with sed

Tags: linux, sed

The file index.jsp contains this string:

```
'+sessionServerId + '' + countryAssetsInternationalization;
```

I need to replace it with this:

```
'+sessionServerId + '' + countryAssetsInternationalization+'&gameServer=https://webserver.com&gameAssets=';
```

I try a lot of possibilities with no results.

```
sed -i 's/\'\+sessionServerId \+ \'\' \+ countryAssetsInternationalization;/\'\+sessionServerId \+ \'\' \+ countryAssetsInternationalization\+\'\&gameServer=https:\/\/webserver.com&gameAssets=\';/g' index.jsp
```

Can you help me? Thank you!

SOLVED:

```
sed -i 's/\+ countryAssetsInternationalization;/\+ countryAssetsInternationalization\+'\''&gameServer=https:\/\/webserver.com\&gameAssets='\'';/g' index.jsp
```

Comment: Does the string literally have `string1=` which needs to be changed to `string2=`? If not, can you share exactly what the string looks like in the file without any of the extra bits.

Comment: You can't have `'` inside a single-quoted string in the shell. There's no escaping inside single quotes.

Comment: Yes my fault

'+sessionServerId + '' + countryAssetsInternationalization;

with

'+sessionServerId + '' + countryAssetsInternationalization+'&gameServer=https://webserver.com&gameAssets=';

Answer (score 2):

I can solve my problem myself:

```
sed -i 's/\+ countryAssetsInternationalization;/\+ countryAssetsInternationalization\+'\''&gameServer=https:\/\/webserver.com\&gameAssets='\'';/g' index.jsp
```

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid `\` is not reliable as a quote character in sed. Replace `\'` and `\+` with `[']` and `[+]` and it seems to start working.

```
sed "s/['][+]sessionServerId [+] [']['] [+] countryAssetsInternationalization;/\'\+sessionServerId \+ \'\' \+ countryAssetsInternationalization\+\'\&gameServer=https:\/\/webserver.com&gameAssets=\';/g" index.jsp
```